# Féminins de « grec » et « néogrec »

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, genre

Les féminins de « grec » et « néogrec » sont respectivement « grecque » et « néogrecque ». Il semble que la féminisation de -C en -CQUE soit réservée exclusivement à ces deux mots, alors que les mots listés ci-bas se féminisent plutôt en laissant tomber le C final :

- « ammoniac »
- « caduc »
- « franc »
- « laïc »
- « micmac »
- « parapublic »
- « public »
- « turc »
- « vioc »

Ma question est donc : d'où viennent ces deux exceptions ?

Comment: Elles viennent du grec!

Comment: Ah ! Dois-je en conclure que les autres mots cités ne viennent pas du grec ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas. Ce n'était qu'une blague que je faisais. Par contre, il est vrai qu'une déclinaison différente s'explique souvent par une racine ou une origine différente.

Comment: @Kareen: Ma réponse spontanée aurait été la même que la tienne, et vérification faite aucun des mots de la liste ne vient du grec. Je ne comprends pas pourquoi le PO différencie public et son composé, aucune raison que tous les composé de public ne suivent pas le même comportement, c'est le contraier qui serait étonnant.

Comment: La féminisation des mots qui se terminent par un *c* au masculin se fait soit par transformation du *c* en *qu* (Turc→ Turque) soit en *ch* (blanc→blanche). Le *c* seul n'est jamais conservé pour des raisons de prononciation. Ceci ne touche pas que la formation du féminin mais c'est la règle pour l'ajout de tout suffixe commençant par un *e* à un mot qui se termine par un *c*. Peu de mots français se terminent par un *c* mais beaucoup conservent le *c* après ajout du suffixe : sec→sèche, sac→sachet, accroc→accrocher.

Comment: Pour moi « micmac»  est un nom commun masculin qui n'a pas de féminin (confirmé par la consultation de mes dictionnaires). S'il en a un je serais curieuse de le connaître. Je ne pense pas non plus qu'on puisse dire que « ammoniaque » soit le féminin d'« ammoniac », c'est un dérivé par ajout de suffixe. « Ammoniac » a deux dérivés qui sont « ammoniaque » et « ammoniacal ». L'ajout du suffixe *a* ne nécessite pas la transformation du *c* en *qu*. Par ailleurs on peut considérer que du point de vue de l'ajout du suffixe du féminin *e* « grec » et « néogrec » sont un seul et même mot.

Comment: @Laure Le TLF dit que le *c* vient d'une « ancienne graphie » et cite Grevisse. On ne peut pas écrire \**greque* parce qu'il faut prononcer le *e* ouvert, mais ça n'explique pas pourquoi on n'écrit pas \**grèque*.

Comment: @Gilles J'avais déjà consulté mon édition papier de Grevisse (1975) et Grec→Grecque n'est cité que dans la liste des mots qui changent le *c* en *qu* mais ne dit pas pourquoi le c est conservé avant le *qu*. Aucune mention de la prononciation du *e* à propos de ce mot, la question du e→è  est par ailleurs traitée dans le même chapitre avec, entre autre, la féminisation des mots se terminant en *er*.

Answer (score 2):

Un 'e' non suivi d'un 'c' se prononcerait différemment. L'exception n'est donc pas sur du vocabulaire mais sur la terminaison.

-EC se féminise en -ECQUE

-C se féminise en -QUE

Cette règle de terminaison est aussi valable pour des mots féminins qui n'ont pas d'équivalent masculin, comme la **Mecque**. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Le fait que grec/grecque est une exception (notons que de mon point de vue, tous les cas devraient être considérés comme des exceptions, jusqu'à ce qu'il y en ait trop) provient très probablement du dédoublement de la consonne destiné à maintenir au féminin le son d'un "e ouvert" (id est le son "è") du masculin. On ne peut dédoubler un "c", donc nous voilà avec un "que" sur les bras. Abracadabra.

Answer (score -1):

Disons quoique de façon un peut mystique (mais l’étymologie n’est-t-elle pas un tissus de mysticisme ⸮) que la langue Grecque a une importance si singulière et même crutiale en français que son statu presque divin lui permet des transgressions peut commune. Dois-je rappeler qu’elle doit au français rien de moins que son alphabet qui se vit même augmenté tardivement d’autres lettres grecques ?

Au delà de la langue française et des langues latines (ou utilisant l’alphbabêt latin) la façon de désigner les grecs fait l’objet d’une curieuse [polymophie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nom_des_Grecs). À défaut donc d’expliquer l’étrange flexion *-cque* on peut au moins supputer que ce bordel étymologique n’augure pas moins :)

Comment: Est-ce le français ou le grec qui hérite d'un alphabet -- ⸮ ne fait pas partie de la typographie francophone (penser à ceux qui débutent) et alphbabêt n'est pas encore dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie française.

Comment: L'alphabet français vient de l'alphabet latin qui vient de l'alphabet étrusque qui vient de l'alphabet grec qui vient de l'alphabet phénicien. Dans cette [généalogie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Généalogie_des_écritures_dérivées_du_protosinaïtique), le grec n'a pas de statut particulier.

Comment: Certes mais ce que j’entendais par là est que c’est la culture grecque qui a directement fourni — et en tant que tel, non par l’intermédiaire d’une autre culture — de nombreuses choses au monde latin et particulièrement dans le domaine linguistique. Quoiqu’on en dise, c’est une référence majeure que n’est ni l’étrusque, ni le phénicien, ni le cananéen ni les hiéroglyphes égyptiens (pour remonter jusqu’au bout la généalogie). Pensez que le grecque était la langue de l’élite sous l’Empire romain.

Comment: Je ne parlais que de l'alphabet. Nous sommes d'accord quant à la culture et à la langue. Il m'arrive même de chercher le sens de mots français dans le Bailly.